# Interprocess data exchange for video editing

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc, ipc

I'm using Visual C++ 2013. 
I have two applications (they run on same machine):

- The first application receives high quality video streams from multiple clients, synchronizes these videos and writes them to video file (only H264, DIVX and MJPG)
- The second application does some processing on each set of synchronized frames in these videos (using OpenCV)

However, I'm get stuck in exchange data between two processes since the read/write task to/from disk is quite slow. So I want to exchange data directly on RAM with low latency and process frame-by-frame.

I've read 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
but I have no idea dealing with this.

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, for video, it definitely makes sense to use shared memory. Microsoft Windows has APIs for that. I have used them for just this sort of thing and they work well.  You need both a mechanism to open shared memory between two processes and a method of synchronization (such as events). You need to explore the Interprocessor Communications section of the Windows OS manuals. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Just wondering, but why do you need a second process at all? Can't you do the OpenCV work in a thread?

Comment: That's the order from customer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it. The most simple one is via `WM_COPYDATA`:

```
 COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
 cds.dwData = 0;
 cds.cbData = 5 * sizeof(WCHAR);
 cds.lpData = L"Hello";

 ::SendMessage(hTargetWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)GetSafeHwnd(), (LPARAM)&cds);
```

You can easily find your target window handle by calling:

```
HWND hTargetWnd = ::FindWindow(NULL, L"AppName");
```

The other method is based on shared memory. If you do use MFC framework there is `CSharedFile` class that implements this type of IPC.

You can also use UDP sockets for IPC. There are several benefits here:

1. There is no need to establish connection
2. The packet loss is almost impossible because the data is transferred via loopback interface.
3. Again if it is MFC-based app I would use `CAsyncSocket` class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have a stream of frames that you then distribute to the worker app for processing. I would consider using ZeroMQ for that. Reasons:

- ZeroMQ is already message-based, so unlike e.g. TCP (stream-based) or UDP (limited frame size), you can transfer large messages without having to worry about fragmentation.
- It manages things like (re-)connecting and some other things that reduce the complexity of your application.
- It has a shared memory transport mechanism (you'd have to check if it is supported under MS Windows though) which should be efficient enough for your use cases.
- It also supports TCP transport, in case you want to distribute the work to multiple machines.
- It has bindings for many languages and for many OSs, in case you want to expand your scope later on.